# how to get file size with fine uploader on submit callback

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

Is there any method to get the size of file selected with Fine Uploader on a `submit` callback?

```
.on('submit', function(obj, fileIndex, fileName){

}
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, when using jQuery event handlers in Fine Uploader, keep in mind that the first parameter is an `Event`.

Second, I strongly suggest you *not* use jQuery event handlers.  Instead, declare your event/callback handler as part of the Fine Uploader initialization options.  If you take this route, you can easily determine the file's size via Fine Uploader's API, specifically the [`getSize` method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getSize).

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
   ...
   callbacks: {
      onSubmit: function(id, name) {
         var size = this.getSize(id);
         ...
      }
   },
   ...
});
```

Keep in mind that the file size is not available in IE9 and older.

Comment: Its a trap with filesize. some linux show metrics * 1000 per kilo, while should be 1024. How to be sure of real size of file ?

Comment: There is nothing OS specific to worry about here